# ASP.NET Client Proxy for IntelliTrace and Test Impact slowing down test execution in Test Manager

Tags: asp.net, iis, selenium, tfs, microsoft-test-manager

I am using Microsoft Test Manager to run my automated tests written with selenium.

I want to be able to know what tests I should run after a code changes. To do so, I have enabled the "Test Impact" adapter on my test settings. After a week i realized that it was not working, and after reading a lot on internet I found out that I should enable also the ASP.NET Client Proxy for IntelliTrace for the Test Impact adapter to work.

But now I am completely lost. There are 2 places where I can enable this adapter: at the Web Client role and at the Web Server role. The Test Adapter can so be enabled in both roles. That is what I did:

[image]

I enabled nothing at the Web Client role.

And here comes my questions:

1 - In which role should I enable the ASP.NET Client Proxy for IntelliTrace and the Test Impact role?

2 - Why does the Web Server and Web Client role have the same adapters and how can I know in which one I should enable an adapter?

3 - When I enabled the ASP.NET Client Proxy for IntelliTrace (it does not matter in which role I do) it slows down my test execution a lot in a point that the test times out because my ASP app does not respond any page at all or takes too much time to respond. If I disable this adapter, everything works fine. I presume that this adapter is injecting some service on the IIS Server and that is why it slows down the requests, but I have no idea why.

I am testing an ASP.net application, MS Test Manager 2013, TFS 2013 and the latest version of Selenium